# CXF interceptor not invoked to read http response

Tags: cxf, httpresponse, interceptor

I am writing the client for a web service and I want to do two things using interceptor-
1) Log the outgoing XML message and 2) Read the HTTP response, not the SOAP response.

The service side has only a void method and they just acknowledge the receipt of my message through the HTTP response code.

This is what their response looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Date: Wed, 10 Jul 2013 23:06:36 GMT
Server: Oracle-Application-Server-11g
Content-Length: 0
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 004sJ1KLm7yB_6RjMX^QsA0002X30001U5
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Content-Type: 
Content-Language: en
X-F5-ServerSSL-Profile: serverssl_sys_soaorexafun
X-F5-ForwardProxy-Host: 64.181.184.15%819 443
```

I need the "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted" response.

My interceptor code is:

```
package com.cambiahealth.orservice.client;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.EndpointSelectionInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CoverOregonServiceInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CoverOregonServiceInterceptor.class.getName());
    private static Integer responseCode = 0;

    public CoverOregonServiceInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.POST_INVOKE);
        addAfter(ReadHeadersInterceptor.class.getName());
        addAfter(EndpointSelectionInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        try{
            responseCode = (Integer) message.get(Message.RESPONSE_CODE);
            logger.info("Response Code is " + responseCode);
        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Failed to read the response code from Soap message", e);
        }        
    }

    public Integer getResponseCode(){
        return responseCode;
    }

}
```

And the code in my client is:

```
String wsdlUrl = coverOregonServiceUrl + "?wsdl";
CoverOregonServiceInterceptor interceptor = new CoverOregonServiceInterceptor();
CoverOregonServiceInterceptor outInterceptor = new CoverOregonServiceInterceptor();
InboundEnrollmentManagementClient client = new InboundEnrollmentManagementClient(
                    new URL(wsdlUrl));
InboundEnrollManagementPortType port = client.getInboundEnrollManagementPort();
Client cxfClient = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
cxfClient.getInInterceptors().add(interceptor); 
cxfClient.getOutFaultInterceptors().add(outInterceptor);
port.statusupdate(request);
```

However, my interceptor is not getting invoked/triggered at all. I tried various different phases - READ, RECEIVE, PRE_INVOKE, POST_INVOKE, INVOKE, POST_STREAM, SEND. But none of them worked. I tried a similar interceptor to log the XML message before sending the request also. And it's not working there as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried with PRE_STREAM (as org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor does)

Comment: PRE_STREAM worked for the logging interceptor to retrieve the XML message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The service I am calling does not have a return so I cannot use the inbound interceptor chain.

```
cxfClient.getInInterceptors().add(interceptor);
```

I used it in the outbound chain and it worked.

```
cxfClient.getOutInterceptors().add(outInterceptor);
```